# Confidence intervals for proportions by svypredmeans()

Tags: r, survey

I am trying to obtain the 95% CI for proportions which are actually predictive marginal means, as computed with the `survey package` for R. I'm including this reproducible example that makes no sense content-wise, but hopefully illustrates well my purpose:

```
library(survey)
data(api)
dstrat <- svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)

# 1.- marginal means for groups according to a variable 
svyglm(I(sch.wide=="Yes") ~ awards+comp.imp, design=dstrat, family=quasipoisson()) %>% svypredmeans(., ~yr.rnd)

# 2.- the confidence intervals I'd like to compute by svyciprop(), in an obviously wrong way   
svyby(I(sch.wide=="Yes") ~ awards+comp.imp, ~yr.rnd, design=dstrat, svyciprop, vartype="ci", method="xlogit")
```

What I can't figure out is how to enter the right arguments into `svyciprop()`, or if this is even possible. The function `svyciprop()` takes a single formula, and this does not seem compatible with the way compute predictive marginal means are computed, nor with the output of `svypredmeans()`.

Thanks beforehand for any help!

**EDIT** Apologies because the code was right, but there was a typo. However, there's a follow-up question: the estimates for the predictive marginal means in step 1 will not match the same estimates in step 2. Can someone shed light on why these differences?

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work for a very simple reason: R is case-sensitive. Change `sch.wide=="yes"` to `sch.wide=="Yes"` and it should work.

Comment: That was totally right! Apologies for rushy typing. Still I have a follow-up question, and so I made the edit accordingly